# Cannot run the macro... the macro may not be available in this workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call a sub on a different worksheet but I got a run time error message.

Specifically, I have two worksheets and multiple VBA sub s in those worksheets. In one of the VBA Project (say workbook1.xlsm), I have the following code:

```
Sub AnalysisTableMacro()
Workbooks("Python solution macro.xlsm").Activate
Application.Run "Python solution macro.xlsm!.PreparetheTables"
End Sub
```

But I got the following error. The macros on both worksheets are enabled. In both worksheets, the subs are in Module1.

> Cannot run the macro 'Workbook.xlsm!PrepareTheTables'. The macro may not be available in >this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

I also tried `Application.Run "Python solution macro.xlsm!Module1.PreparetheTables"` but did not work.

Answer (score 23):

If you have a space in the name of the workbook you must use single quotes (') around the file name. I have also removed the full stop.

```
Application.Run "'Python solution macro.xlsm'!PreparetheTables"
```

Answer (score 15):

In my case this error came up when the Sub name was identical to the Module name.

Comment: Had a macro that worked in automated Excel 2003, but didn't when I moved to Excel 2010. Renamed the Sub and it worked. Now I have to go back and check every VBA file.

Comment: @ourmandave is correct.  I added a button to the ribbon using XML and ran into this issue.  Changing the name of the module so it wasn't identical to the name of the method solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue and I 'Compiled VBA Project' which identified an error. After correction and compiling, the macros worked.

Answer (score 8):

You also run into this issue when you are creating routine in a class module.

When you try to run the code externally, you get this error.
You can't assign macro to button to a member of a class module either.

If you try to run from within the code by pressing green play button you will also see the same error.

Either move the routine in to a regular module or create a new routine in a regular module that calls the class member.

Answer (score 7):

Per [Microsoft's KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813969), try allowing programmatic access to the Visual Basic project:

> 1. Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options.
> 2. Click Trust Center.
> 3. Click Trust Center Settings.
> 4. Click Macro Settings.
> 5. Click to select the Trust access to the VBA project object model check box.
> 6. Click OK to close the Excel Options dialog box.
> 7. You may need to close and re-open excel.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but since this Q&A is being linked to, there needs to be a comment here that says **DON'T DO THIS**. This is terrible, unjustified advice that is outright dangerous. Don't tick that checkbox unless you're doing actual meta-programming in VBA, or need to run code that does. This answer is wholly inappropriate for this OP here. The ONLY reason to check this box is if you're using the VBIDE API *and you know what you're doing*. Otherwise, this is a massive macro-virus security hole.

Comment: Just to tempter Mathieu Guindon's comment here with a little realism - it's not uncommon to do this in industry, as it is a constructive step that leads to actually being able to call a macro. The security hole that it leaves is not prohibitive, in my opinion. Not that you should just do this gung ho, but this option isn't worth rejecting outright.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the error happened when I placed my macro (public sub) into a `ThisWorkbook` section of the file expecting it will make it visible for `Application.Run` function. This was not the case and I got that error you mentioned.

I moved my macro into a separate Module and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Go into task manager and see if you have any Microsoft Excel Processes running in the background. I closed my excel background processes and my code worked again.

Comment: So simple. I was facing this problem so I checked if there was a Excel process running. It was there! I killed it. It worked. So now I believe the problem is that sometimes an Excel process can be running without control in the machine. It must be killed to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove all dashes and underscores from file names and macro names, make sure that macro were enabled and add them module name.macro name

This is what I ended up with: `Application.Run ("'" & WbName & "'" & "!ModuleName.MacroName")`

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with this error as well, turned out the the filename was causing the problem.

I was calling it like this:
`Application.Run "'" & strPath & strFName & "'!UPC.PrintaFew"`

The variable strFName contained an apostrophe in it which, of course messed things up. Took me hours to figure it out. But once the apostrophe was removed from the filename it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your name macro and build again.
I did this, and the macro worked.

Comment: I'm not excited about this solution (naturally), but when the other recommendations failed this one succeeded

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to create a module and write the code there.

Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EVxKkE9p1M

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as OP and found was due to the options declaration being misspelled:

```
' Comment comment  

Options Explicit  

Sub someMacroMakechart()
```

in a sub module, instead of correct;

```
' Comment comment  

Option Explicit  

Sub someMacroMakechart()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs if you create a sub or function in a 'Microsoft Excel Object' (like Sheet1, Sheet2, ...) instead to create it in a Module.

For example:
you create with VBA a button and set `.OnAction = 'btn_action'` . And `Sub btn_action` you placed into the Sheet object instead into a Module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message "Cannot find the macro ___ etc" and this problem persisted even after I'd saved the file as an XLSX. This seemed very odd ... how could it be running a macro when the file has no macros!

When I examined the file using the Custom UI Editor, I found that a macro was being called when the file was initialized and another custom macro was being called when the user clicked the Save button.

Using the Custom UI Editor, I removed all the XML code and the error messages disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the macro I wished to run was assigned to a button on a worksheet (Forms button as opposed to ActiveX button).

The macro was defined not in the workbook, but in a separate .xlam addin. Clicking the button gave an error: `Cannot run the macro 'NameOfMyMacro'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.`

None of the answers given here worked for me, but what did work was to make the folder of the workbook a "Trusted Location".

See Ribbon -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Trusted Locations -> Add new Location

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a security issue that I resolved by unblocking the file in explorer (Properties / Unblock).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when a sub was assigned programically using OnAction property. To make it work you need to provide the exact path for example 'My Workbook.xlsm'!MyMacroScript

```
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "MyMacroScript"
```

Comment: I see `"'"` in two places. If single quotes are allowed in this context AND if the double quotes at the right end of the first occurrence and at the  left end of the second were deleted , it might work: i.e., `.OnAction = "' & ThisWorkbook.Name & '!" & "MyMacroScript"`. However, using `""`  instead of `'` might be better; i.e.,  `.OnAction = """ & ThisWorkbook.Name & ""!" & ""MyMacroScript"""`.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone tried setting the `Application.AutomationSecurity` to 1 (msoAutomationSecurityLow)?

Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.automationsecurity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoautomationsecurity

Answer (score 0):

I had my code working, then decided to rename my function `insertSelection` to the more sensible `insertAtSelection`. Then I immediately went to lunch. (*What could go wrong*?)

When I got back to it, I started getting the `Cannot run the macro insertSelection; the macro may not be available in this workbook`, which floored me. All was well an hour ago.

So I then took a long break to try to clear my brain.

The `OnKey` hotkey was originally (and still was) defined as `OnKey "^+I", "insertSelection"`  (Ctrl+Shift+I), but after the change I didn't remember to change the function name in my `OnKey` definition to include `At`. The `OnKey` definitions are in another module. Eventually I recalled this omission.

So the error message was correct: `the macro insertSelection WAS NOT available in this workbook`--`insert*At*Selection` was.

`OnKey "^+I", "insertAtSelection"` worked and I said to myself, "CAREFUL!!!"