# Why would a macro from a different workbook be inaccesible after allowing macro's?

Tags: vba, module, call, xlsm, xlsb

I have an .xlsb file, which I'm running on a different computer, after defining the paths variable and dependent on its current location. I added the VBA Project of a different xlsm file to the .xlsb. And I'm trying to run a macro from Module 2 of the .xlsb file with either one of the following lines in the following code:

```
Dim path As String
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
path = path & "\"

Workbooks("2cDataSet.xlsm").Activate
'MsgBox (path & "2cDataSet.xlsm!publicdatahandler")
'Application.Run (path & "2cDataSet.xlsm!publicDataHandler")
'Application.Run (path & "'2cDataSet.xlsm'!publicDataHandler")
'Application.Run (path & "2cDataSet.xlsm!Module2.publicDataHandler")
'Application.Run (path & "'2cDataSet.xlsm'!Module2.publicDataHandler")

'Application.Run ("2cDataSet.xlsm!publicDataHandler")
'Application.Run ("'2cDataSet.xlsm'!publicDataHandler")
'Application.Run ("2cDataSet.xlsm!Module2.publicDataHandler")
'Application.Run ("'2cDataSet.xlsm'!Module2.publicDataHandler")

'Application.Run "2cDataSet.xlsm!publicDataHandler"
'Application.Run "'2cDataSet.xlsm'!publicDataHandler"
'Application.Run "2cDataSet.xlsm!Module2.publicDataHandler"
'Application.Run "'2cDataSet.xlsm'!Module2.publicDataHandler"

'Application.Run path & "2cDataSet.xlsm!publicDataHandler"
'Application.Run path & "'2cDataSet.xlsm'!publicDataHandler"
'Application.Run path & "2cDataSet.xlsm!Module2.publicDataHandler"
'Application.Run path & "'2cDataSet.xlsm'!Module2.publicDataHandler"

'Run macro:="2cDataSet.xlsm!Module2.publicdatahandler"
'Run macro:="2cDataSet.xlsm!publicdatahandler"
```

It appears to be the same problem as here, except I expect the problem in this case to be caused by the fusion of the 2 different excel files rather than the un-enabledness of the macro's:

[Cannot run the macro... the macro may not be available in this workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389562/cannot-run-the-macro-the-macro-may-not-be-available-in-this-workbook)

Because as it suggests I have manually enabled the macros and object security settings by:

1. Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options.
2. Click Trust Center.
3. Click Trust Center Settings.
4. Click Macro Settings.
5. Click to select the Trust access to the VBA project object model check box.
6. Click OK to close the Excel Options dialog box.
7. Close and re-open excel.

I also clicked the "enable macro buttons above that objectmodel checkbox.

I tried first manually opening the 2cDataSet.xlsm first and manually enabling the macro's when prompted, and then opening the parent .xlsb, and the other way round (where the .xlsm is automatically opend without prompting for enabling macros after enabling the macros for the .xlsb)

And I think I've tried the right syntax in any of the options tried. *By now I'm also aware the single ' is only used in case the name contains spaces.

I have not deleted the macro and recreated it.

I checked whether the "option explicit" wasn't written as "options explicit" but it wasn't written at all

The sub is public.

The office I wrote it in was 2016, the version on the other pc is 2013, but I got the same error in the 2016 office, but for some, to me unknown reason, sometimes after switching the calling of the sub syntax or re-opening the excel file, the error did not occur anymore or not consistenly.

Any suggestions on why excel gives the following error:

> cannot run the macro the macro may not be available in this workbook
>   or all macros may be disabled

after the sub is called?

Ps. It's for a distributed automated computation, so I will not be able to edit pc (or excel) settings, and popups are a nono :)

The problem was that after merging the vba projects, excel kept the reference to the .xlsm file to the old folder even though the parent .xlsb file was copied and moved to a different path.

The solution is currently being verified as being: Moving the original file into the folder of the new parent file, and sharing that entire folder with the actual .xlsm included, to be run on a different computer

Comment: _"I added the VBA Project of a different xlsm"_ but "xlsm" is the extension for "plain" excel files i.e. with no VBA Modules in it.  Are you sure `acDataSet.xlsm` is the right name of the workbook to add as VBA project reference?

Comment: @user3598756 - **xlsx** is what I call a naked file :) **xlsm** - the **m** is for macros ;)

Comment: @Irithyll right, I was mistaken between xlsm-xlsb and xlsx-xlsm.

Answer (score 0):

> I added the VBA Project of a different xlsm file to the .xlsb.

You have to open the *.xlsm like this:

```
Sub openFile_RunMacro()

     Workbooks.Open "File2.xlsm" 'if File2.xlsm is in the same path as File1.xslb

     'otherwise » Workbooks.Open path & "File2.xlsm" «

     Application.Run ("File2.xlsm!Test")

End Sub
```

If the message for activating macros is annoying you, try to set the used path as a **trusted location**.

**Edit**

> I'm trying to run a macro from Module 2 of the **.xlsb** file with either one of the following lines in the following code

So you're trying to run code from the **.xlsb**-file? Then you've to change the filename in your code from **.xlsm** to **.xlsb**.

[image: Trusted Locations]

Comment: I do no know what you meant with set the path as a trusted location, I assume it's a pc -rather than excel setting. 

I am trying to run the code from the xlsb-file, but it was not a problem that the other merged vba project was from a .xlsm file. 

Thank you for your suggestions though :)

Comment: @MaximilianbrutusIII - I'm adding a picture to my answer -> trusted locations. It's an Excel option File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trusted Locations :)

Comment: Ah, thank you, that expands my knowledge. Also, if the problem is not solved by incorporating the original .xlsm file in the new folder, I shall give that a try to see whether it helps the issue.