# Passing variables from QTP/UFT to Excel macros

Tags: excel, automated-tests, qtp, vba

I have some txt files to import to Excel. These files are grouped by date. I recorded macro in Excel where each time I have to change the path to file for each date as ...\files(date)\filename.txt. Here is the macro:

```
Sub DataImport2()
'
' DataImport2 Macro
'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;d:\testfiles\project1\20170528\filename.txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
'        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "filename.txt"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

In automated test, UFT should pick a date in webpage and compare data on the webpage with data in files for that date.

Question is: How to pass that picked date from UFT to Excel and use it in Excel as path to file? I guess it should look like

```
..."TEXT;d:\testfiles\project1\(uft-passed-date)\filename.txt" _...
```

Maybe passing variables as following might work, but from Excel/macro side how should I use them?

```
objExcel.Run "macroname", "params1", "param2"
```

I tried to copy above macro to UFT, but it did not work (General Error).
Working on UFT 12.52, IE11 and Office 16.

Comment: Create `String` variable for your sub `DataImport2` to pass file name. Now extract date from GUI using UFT and then [run your excel macro from UFT](https://www.google.com/search?q=run+excel+macro+using+vbscript&oq=run+excel+macro+using+vbscript&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.11008j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @ManishChristian in UFT I have `vDate=Browser("").Page("").WebElement("").GetROProperty("")`
I can run the macro as
`objExcel.Run "DataImport2", "vDate"`
In Excel, how the macro can get that? What should be modified in the recorded macro?
Thnx)

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First modify your macro like this to add date parameter:

```
Sub DataImport2(dDate as String)
'
' DataImport2 Macro
'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;d:\testfiles\project1\" & dDate & "\filename.txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
```

Then in UFT, capture the date from GUI and convert it to format of your file name(if require).

And lastly run your macro from UFT like this:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("ExcelFilePath\FileName.xlsm", 0, True)
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Run "DataImport2", sDate 'sDate variable holding date
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objWorkbook = Nothing : Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Thnx a lot.
But now I am getting error "The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled") Macro is enabled in Excel, is in Module. "Trust access to the VBA project " is selected.
When I run the marco from Excel, it works

Comment: Where are you storing your macro, is in Module or sheet level?

Comment: It is stored in Module

Comment: Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18389562/1652222) link, see if any answer help you. Because I've tested every bit of my answer and its working without any issue.

Comment: It works.
Had to rewrite the macro in new file.
While declaring sDate as String in macro, it returns error. I left it not declared as string, and it works:

`Sub DataImport2(sDate)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the macro to this so that it can take the `picked date`

```
Sub DataImport2(sFilePart As String)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;d:\testfiles\project1\" & sFilePart & "\filename.txt" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```