# Excel Cannot Run Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Please help. For some reasons, any Excel file that contains Macro does not work stating that the "The Macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disable". I changed the settings in the trust center but with no luck, still does not run at all.

Many thanks,

Comment: Needs more details on exactly how you're trying to run your macro.

Comment: Hi Tims, there are no problems with my Macro as I've been running this a couple of times before. Also, the problem is within my computer as I've sent out the macro to other users and everything seem to work fine. So I'm guessing this is more of an internal/hardware issue rather than the codes itself.

Comment: I think it's the security options in your workbook that might have been changed... Could be that the [trust center service give the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389562/cannot-run-the-macro-the-macro-may-not-be-available-in-this-workbook).

Comment: I did already change the setting in the trust center so not sure what's next.

Comment: so confused why it works on other pc's but not with mine

Comment: I was asking *exactly how you're trying to run your macro*.

Comment: Please include in your question: ① Which file format you use (extension). ② Where the procedure is located (ThisWorkbook, Module, Worksheet). ③ How you're trying to run that procedure (By button, in VB Editor, via Ribbon, via shortcut). ④ Include the code of that macro in your question.

Comment: xlsm. procedure is located through module and it is triggered by a button within a worksheet. as I told, there are no issues with the macro itself as it is running perfectly as well with our desktop. Its just my pc doesn't run the macro stating it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but posting for others that may be looking for a solution. Try the solution posted at the link below: browse to the location of the file and open the file under the option "Open and Repair", this repaired the hidden macros for me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udWse.png)
https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-excel-error-unable-to-save-excel-workbook/