# Couldn't execute Excel Macro using Python

Tags: python-3.x

why couldn't I use the script below to run a Macro by Python? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb= xw.Book('C:\\myfolder\\path\\myFileName.xlsm')
a = wb.macro("z_ColumnClear.Column_Clear")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is from this link. 
https://www.excelcise.org/running-excel-vba-from-python/

and this link provides several scenario from users when the script don't work.
[Cannot run the macro... the macro may not be available in this workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389562/cannot-run-the-macro-the-macro-may-not-be-available-in-this-workbook/50293644)

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32

def run_excel_macro (file_path_no_extention, VBA_macro_name, VBA_procedure_name):
"""
Execute an Excel macro
:param file_path: path to the Excel file holding the macro
:param VBA_module_name: VBA name
:param VBA_procedure_name: name in the sub routine
:param separator_char: the character used by the operating system to separate pathname components
:return: None
"""
xl = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Application.visible = False

# os.sep is \
try:
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(file_path_no_extention))
    xl.Application.run("'" + file_path_no_extention.split(sep=os.sep)[-1] + "'" + "!" + VBA_macro_name + "." + VBA_procedure_name)
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()

except Exception as ex:
    template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
    message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
    print(message)

xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
print("Completed: " + str(file_path_no_extention.split(sep=os.sep)[-1]))
```